# Accuracy of results for spring.io guide accessing-data-neo4j?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I ran a spring.io guide for neo4j, and it did not return expected results.

For a sanity check, I was not sure where else to go for this. Running the spring guide with this [documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/) does not return results as expected. The docs state results will be similar to:

```
Before linking up with Neo4j...
    Greg's teammates => []
    Roy's teammates => []
    Craig's teammates => []

Lookup each person by name...
    Greg's teammates => [Roy, Craig]
    Roy's teammates => [Greg, Craig]
    Craig's teammates => [Roy, Greg]
```

However, in two instances, each on a different system, I got back the following:

```
Before linking up with Neo4j...
    Greg's teammates => []
    Roy's teammates => []
    Craig's teammates => []

Lookup each person by name...
    Greg's teammates => [Roy, Craig]
    Roy's teammates => [Craig]
    Craig's teammates => []
```

Yes, they are similar but not the same. Can someone confirm their own results for the same guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the guide and it seems that the expected output is wrong.
My assumption is that it is a left-over of the old Spring Data Neo4j / Neo4j-OGM behaviour when there was a bi-directional relationship definition (also judging from the comment above the relationship in the `Person` class).

For completeness I add the relationship creation code here:

```
greg = personRepository.findByName(greg.getName());
greg.worksWith(roy);
greg.worksWith(craig);
personRepository.save(greg);

roy = personRepository.findByName(roy.getName());
roy.worksWith(craig);
// We already know that roy works with greg
personRepository.save(roy);

// We already know craig works with roy and greg
```

Also looking at the comments there, I would definitely say that the assumptions are just plain wrong.
The `worksWith` function only adds the relationship on the calling object and not the opposite.

So either the guide has to change the behaviour of the `worksWith` function or the expected output *and* the comments needs to get changed.

tl;dr;
Your output is correct for me compared with the application's code.